# C# - Add rows to a existing dataGridView using a textdocument

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm currently adding data to my `dataGridView1` using the `Form1_Load` load event. Now I'm trying to add more data from a textfile which im loading into the winforms application.

As you guys will see, I'm trying to add more rows into the `dataGridView1` but those new rows wont be added. What am I doing wrong?

I appreciate any kind of suggestions and help.

**getTexFilePath function code:**

```
private void getTexFilePath()
{
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
    openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
    openFileDialog1.Title = "Browse Text Files";

    openFileDialog1.CheckFileExists = true;
    openFileDialog1.CheckPathExists = true;

    openFileDialog1.DefaultExt = "txt";
    openFileDialog1.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
    openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
    openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

    openFileDialog1.ReadOnlyChecked = true;
    openFileDialog1.ShowReadOnly = true;

    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        filePath = openFileDialog1.FileName;

        foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines(filePath))
        {
            var index = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
            dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells["Column1"].Value = line;
            dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells["Column2"].Value = "undefined";
        }

    }
}
```

**Form1_Load code:**

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("Username", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("Links");

    table.Rows.Add("No File uploaded", "Missing data");

    dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not knowing all of your requirements, this would be where I'd start.

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace DatagridView_AddRowsAfterInitialLoad_45922121
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string filePath = "";

        BindingList<dgventry> dgvSourceList = new BindingList<dgventry>();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeDGV();
            //put initial values in the grid
            dgvSourceList.Add(new dgventry { field1 = "yeah", field2 = "yeah in f2", field3 = "yeah in F3" });
            //put values from the datafile
            getTexFilePath();
        }

        private void InitializeDGV()
        {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dgvSourceList;
        }

        private void getTexFilePath()
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
            openFileDialog1.Title = "Browse Text Files";

            openFileDialog1.CheckFileExists = true;
            openFileDialog1.CheckPathExists = true;

            openFileDialog1.DefaultExt = "txt";
            openFileDialog1.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
            openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
            openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

            openFileDialog1.ReadOnlyChecked = true;
            openFileDialog1.ShowReadOnly = true;

            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                filePath = openFileDialog1.FileName;

                foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines(filePath))
                {
                    dgvSourceList.Add(new dgventry { field1 = line, field2 = "", field3 = "" });
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class dgventry
    {
        public string field1 { get; set; }
        public string field2 { get; set; }
        public string field3 { get; set; }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `Form1_Load` you use a data source (`DataTable` instance) so your grid is data bound (means, the grid reflects the content of its source).

However, in `getTexFilePath` you just try to add rows to the grid itself in an unbound manner.

**Solution 1**

You should add new lines to your underlying `DataTable` instead.

**Solution 2**

Create a new table and reset the binding:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = null;

DataTable newDataTable = ReadFileAsDataTable(fileName); // implement this
dataGridView1.DataSource = newDataTable;
```

**Solution 3**

Use a non-bound grid also in `Load` event, similarly to your `getTexFilePath`. But this is not recommended because in this case you do not have a clean UI independent model object (data source), and you can read business data only from the UI control, which is nasty.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to deal with this is to have your DataTable table as a member of your form class.  So in Form_Load you just have:

```
table = new DataTable();
```

Then in your foreach loop in GetTexFilePath use the following:

```
DataRow dR = table.NewRow();
dR[0] = line;
dR[1] = "undefined";
table.rows.Add(dR);
```